# Hindi language not displaying correctly on tcpdf

Tags: php, utf-8, tcpdf, hindi

i have created below code for displaying hindi text using arial unicode font in tcpdf

```
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);


//set some language-dependent strings
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

$pdf->addTTFfont('fonts/ARIALUNI.TTF', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
$pdf->SetFont('arialuni', '', 10,'false');

$txt = 'hindi text with arial unicode समृध्दि';

$pdf->Write(0, $txt, '', 0, 'L', true, 0, false, false, 0);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example_038.pdf', 'I');
```

but it is not getting displayed properly

But in php it showing correct text.

Please tell me if there is anything wrong.

Comment: so i don't understand. if code works.. where is the problem???

Comment: You should add that it is being *displayed* **differently**.

Comment: i want to print समृध्दि t this hindi text but it not showing exactly same in pdf. this is the problem

Comment: In my PDF reader I can find this word in text using search with "समृध्दि". Looks like everything is ok

Comment: it seems tcpdf is not recognizing utf characters properly. समृध्दि is a bit complex word try using simple utf8 words. or try different combination on http://google.com/transliterate/indic  try writing in hindi, marathi and other devnagri fonts,  something may work

Comment: i have got solution, now i used MPDF for this, its working fine. example link -: http://mpdf1.com/examples/example_utf8.pdf

Comment: You should let TCPDF know :)

Answer (score 2):

Try [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com) as an alternative. It is very good and easy to use. [Here is an example](http://mpdf1.com/examples/example_utf8.pdf) of how it displays Hindi

Answer (score 0):

I would try [mpdf1.com](http://mpdf1.com/)
I have tried it before, and it worked with hindi

Answer (score -1):

Something could be wrong with the font.

Try replacing the following lines and trying another font:

```
$pdf->addTTFfont('fonts/ARIALUNI.TTF', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
$pdf->SetFont('arialuni', '', 10,'false');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it works.

$mpdf->SetAutoFont();